# Показы вопросов происходят по IP на основном сайте, а на Мете от количества обновлений страницы

Tags: дефект, статус-отклонено, показы

Случайно заметила, что если обновить страницу на `Meta`, то количество просмотров увеличивается, и можно бесконечно кликать, и увеличивать число просмотров

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

на основном сайте не так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Это так задуманно ?

Comment: Не подтверждаю, на мете после обновления страницы счетчик не тикает, или не всегда тикает

Comment: @aepot я 5 раз кликнула и со 104 до 109 дошла, и так постоянно, бывает, что раз десять прибавил, потом закрыл страницу, через минуту открыл и еще раз десять можно прибавить, а на основном сайте не так //может у меня ip необычный ‍♀️

Comment: В любом случае здесь вряд-ли мы сможем это отнести куда нужно. Возможно стоит это на английской MSE опубликовать.

Comment: Инглиш бэт май вери ☹️

Comment: Где-то 6-7 просмотров можно накрутить обновлениями что на мете, что на основном сайте. Возможно, так было всегда.

Comment: У меня не воспроизводится.

Comment: У меня не воспроизводится. (У меня Linux Mint и браузер Brave).

Comment: Накрутилось [со 134 до 141](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e6ejm.gif), например.

Comment: А я следом 141-149

Comment: через телефон работает, но через раз. после перезагрузки не меняется, а при следующей сразу +2

Comment: Теперь я знаю, как на Мете заработать много знаков "Популярный вопрос")...

Comment: Уже 500... Такими темпами можно и золотой знак заполучить(

Comment: Теперь от 501 до 505 дошло и застряло.

Comment: Странно, что на хром работает, на экплоуэр(или как там его по новому) работает, а на мозила вообще без отклика. Те тянешь страницу вниз, обновить а в ответ тишина...

Comment: @чистов_n все на том же линукс?

Comment: Можно жать на заголовок вопроса, чтобы обновить страницу. Если до браузерной кнопки обновления сложно дотянуться и обновление другим способом (типа потянуть вниз) почему-то не работает на мобильной версии.

Comment: У меня воспроизводится. ОС - windows 7, Браузер - chrome 109.0.5414.120, 32 бита. Попробовал накрутить просмотры ещё на какой-нибудь другой мете - получилось: [этому](https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/q/484/203420) вопросу на мете Русского Языка накрутил с 151 до 158.

Comment: @Dev18 конечно на linux! У меня Windows-то есть, но я им не пользуюсь. После двух лет эксплуатации, я его не переношу!

Comment: У меня не воспроизводится. Chrome, IP динамический.

Comment: Вот и накрутили на [популярный вопрос](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/26/popular-question?userid=264178)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из-за незначительного влияния этой ошибки и нашего текущего списка приоритетов мы решили пометить это как статус-отклонено.